# Create plotly express histogram with defined bin interval python

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I am trying to set a custom bin interval for my data in `plotly.express.histogram` but am failing. I feel this should be pretty simple. Here is what I have:

```
df
x      y
0.2    'red'
-0.1    'yellow'
-0.04    'orange'
0.07    'red'
0.2    'red'
```

I want a histogram with the following bins:
`[-1, -.2, -.1, -.05, 0, .05, .1, .2, 1]`

I have tried to do this both inside plotly and without. My attempt is:

```
bins = pd.IntervalIndex.from_tuples([(-1, -.2), (-.19999, -.1), (-.09999, -.05), (-.04999, 0),
                                 (0.0001, .05), (0.05001, .1), (0.1001, .2), (0.2001, 1)])

df['differences'] = pd.cut(df['x'].values, bins)
intervals = df[['x', 'differences']].groupby('differences').count().reset_index()

fig = px.histogram(intervals, 'differences')
fig.show()
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Object of type Interval is not JSON serializable
```

Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `groupby` or create the `intervals` DataFrame. Just use your original DataFrame with the "differences" column cast to `str`:

```
fig = px.histogram(df["differences"].sort_values().astype(str))
fig.show()
```

Comment: The issue with creating this as a string, is that the x axis is not ordered. Is there any way to do this?